# Hazelcast Eviction on Update

Tags: java, hazelcast

The eviction policy is set as LFU, but I am updating each element after some time. Does update an element reset the eviction counter?

Answer (score 0):

If you update entry itself (outside the map), it do not affect eviction counter.
If you get the entry from map or put it to map, it updates eviction counter.